# Why does this script not open parallel gnome-terminals on a server?

Tags: server, gnome-terminal, vnc

Why am I not able to have parallel `gnome-terminal`s on my server while I can on my client.

Here is a test that illustrates the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is the parent script
gnome-terminal --command "./left.sh"
gnome-terminal --command "./right.sh"

#!/bin/bash
echo "this is the left script"
read -p "press any key to close this terminal" key

#!/bin/bash
echo "this is the right script"
read -p "press any key to close this terminal" key
```

When I run this on a regular ubuntu desktop (maverick) I see two terminals.  When I run this on a maverick server at a server farm, the second window does not appear until **after I close the first one**.  I am using tightvncserver to view the server desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` running locally uses a background "factory" server which owns the actual terminal windows; the `gnome-terminal` command itself exits after contacting the server over DBus and telling it to launch a window.  When running remotely, it does not have the ability to communicate with a factory server, so it sets up the window itself and must continue running until that window is closed.

If you put the command in the background with `&` you will get the effect you want regardless of remote or local (or use of `--disable-factory` which would cause the local ones to behave like the remote ones).  You probably want a final `wait` command in the script in that case.

Comment: It seems that even the `&` for backgrounding is not needed if VNC is used to run the scripts.  The & helps if you are using an SSH console on the client to run the remote script.